# Redirect cin to a string

Tags: c++, iostream

I want to have `cin` read input from a string.

Is there a way to do this?

Something like this:

```
const char * s = "123 ab";
cin.readFrom(s); // <---- I want something like this

int i;
cin>>i;

cout<<i; //123
```

Comment: If you want to use a char array instead of a std:string you could use cin.getline (s,n); Where n is the "number of characters to store (including the terminating null character)". See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/. There's also a getline for std::string, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Comment: @anno: Read `cin` **from** a string, not from `cin` into a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::istringstream stream("Some string 123");
streambuf* cin_backup = std::cin.rdbuf(stream.rdbuf());
```

You might want to back up the original rdbuf of std::cin, if you want to use it again.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using a string stream. You can use the overloaded I/O operators like you would with standard in/standard out. Something like this:

```
string tempString = "123 ab";
int firstArg;
string secondArg;

stringstream stream(tempString);

stream >> firstArg >> secondArg;

cout << firstArg << " " << secondArg;
```

I would personally find this to be a little more clear than reading in a string to standard in and then using standard in's I/O operators, but maybe there's a reason you want to read it to standard in first that I don't realize.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
stringbuf s = string("123 ab");
cin.rdbuf(&s);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++17, [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt)'s solution won't compile unless you use `basic_stringbuf`. Instead use the one below:

```
  stringbuf s;
  const char *userInput = "10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 3 7";         
  s.sputn(userInput, strlen(userInput)); 
  cin.rdbuf(&s);
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can use this -

```
#include <string>

std::string str;

std::cin >> str;

if(str == "text")
{
    std::cout << "done";
}
```