# redirect cin to a string in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirect cin to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925150/redirect-cin-to-a-string)

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162068/redirect-both-cout-and-stdout-to-a-string-in-c-for-unit-testing) on how to redirect `cout` to a string. But how to redirect the `cin` to a string, just like redirecting `cin` to a file using `freopen`, so that when I do `cin>>a_int;`, I will get an int from the string? Can I do similarly with `setbuf (stdin , buffer);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this with your end goal in mind...

> when I do cin>>a_int;, I will get an int from the string?

You can do that **without redirecting `cin`** by using `std::istringstream`

Usage would look like this.

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream is(your_string);
is >> a_int;
```

Comment: I know this. But I need to `cin>>a_int` to get the number.please remove your answer so that i can delete this post. it is a duplicate.

Comment: That other question already has the answer, but perhaps you should consider why you have to redirect `cin` instead of using a `stringstream` directly. Remember, `cin` and `cout` are global variables and you should treat them just like any global variables; avoid them as much as possible. You can write better code by passing the streams you need as parameters, and if you need to access the standard input and output then you can pass `cin` and `cout` as parameters.