# Redirecting stdout to file

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to redirect cin and cout to files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)

I'm debugging some spaghetti code which writes to the terminal via std::cout and via a third party library called tecla:

http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~mcs/tecla/

I would like to hook myself into the stdout so that I can redirect it to a file. Before saving to file I can convert the strings to hex representations so that I can more easily identify all the control characters they contain.

I can also log to this file various events within the program so as to better understand how the program is working.

Any suggestions on how I might do this?

**UPDATE**

My program also receives commands on the terminal via std input. It seems doing:

myprogram 9889 > output.txt

or even

myprogram 9889 | xxd

disrupts the program in some manner such that I cant seem to get the program to respond to inputted commands.

The prompt (>) does not appear in output.txt.

Comment: You can just save the output of any process in the terminal / windows command line by saying `process > filename`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a UNIX-oid system, apart from directly storing into a file (as seen in the other answers), you can view it in HEX-encoding and browse it with the cursor keys by combining `hexdump` and `less`:

```
./myProgram | hexdump -C | less
```

The output then looks like:

```
00000000  73 6f 6d 65 20 63 72 79  70 74 69 63 20 6f 75 74  |some cryptic out|
00000010  70 75 74 20 66 72 6f 6d  20 6d 79 20 70 72 6f 63  |put from my proc|
00000020  65 73 73 0a                                       |ess.|
00000024
```

To view (browse using less) + save in a file simutanously, just add a `tee` command in this command pipe:

```
./myProgram | hexdump -C | tee output.txt | less    #for hex-encoded file content

./myProgram | tee output.txt | hexdump -C | less    #for 1:1 file content
```

To also include the `stderr` output in the file / view, merge the two channels before processing it by prepending the process command line with `2>&1`:

```
./myProgram 2>&1 | ...
```

Comment: On windows you could use cygwin to gain access to hexdump and less with the same syntax as above even when executing windows console applications.

Comment: @Baz Did you try the `tee` command? This will output the `stdout` of your process still on the terminal and allows you to do some input to `stdin`. Should be seamless (it logs as a *copy* in the specified filename, not *redirect*)

Answer (score 1):

Writing to `std::cout` is very bad practice, except in small
test programs.  But since you're stuck with it, in code you
cannot change: it's possible to change the `streambuf` to which
the stream writes, with something like the following:

```
class WrappedOutputFilebuf : public std::filebuf
{
    std::ostream& mySavedStream;
    std::streambuf* mySavedStreambuf;
public:
    WrappedOutputFilebuf( std::ostream& stream, std::string filename )
        : mySavedStream( stream)
        , mySavedStreambuf( stream.rdbuf() )
    {
        open( filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::out );
        if ( ! is_open() ) {
            throw some_error;
        }
        stream.rdbuf( this );
    }
    ~WrappedOutputFilebuf()
    {
        mySavedStream.rdbuf( mySavedStreambuf );
    }
};
```

Then just declare it somewhere:

```
WrappedOutputFilebuf w( std::cout, fileName );
```

and as long as the variable is in scope, `std::cout` will output
to the file you've specified.

Comment: Why is writing out to `std::cout` very bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting output to a file is something you usually do on the command line, not inside your code itself. For example:

```
myProgram > output.txt
```

Comment: It's not only bash, it's also the same syntax for Windows CLI. :) (except the `./`)

Comment: Thanks! I don't spend much time in the Windows terminal.

Comment: @Baz Directing `stdout` into a file or another program shouldn't disrupt input at all. I'm not sure what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just run your program by typing:

```
myprogram > output.txt
```

Then view the output.txt file using a hex editor such as WinHex or ghex2.

Answer (score 0):

If the program you're debugging is sensitive to whether it's talking to a terminal, you might look at [`screen`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), in particular [its logging capabilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Logging).