# Threaded input issues

Tags: c++, multithreading, io

I'm very new to threads, and am trying to create a basic asynchronous input program.

[main.cpp] :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

void ThreadedOutput(void) {
    while(true) {
        std::string output="Distracting output!\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        std::cout << output;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    std::thread active_thread(&ThreadedOutput);
    active_thread.detach();

    std::string input;

    while(input!=std::string("password")) {
        std::cin >> input;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The intention of this is to print output while a user is inputting text.
However, it prints the output onto the input line, which interferes with the input.
Is there a way to make it print above the input line?

Screenshot : 
[image: incorrect]

Comment: You protect shared resources with std::mutex.  A console is no exception.

Comment: Mutex blocks resources when other threads are using them, correct? I'm however trying to use cout at the same time as cin.

Comment: No, a mutex blocks *code* that tries to use a shared resource that's not thread-safe.  Big difference.  So if you use it right then you can prevent your cout statements from executing while the cin hasn't returned yet.  Pretty well covered in any introductory book about threading btw.  Never skip reading one, threading is hard to get right and intuition doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can redirect the cin buffer into a file (or other stream) and then display it with cout.

[How to redirect cin and cout to files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)

The problem now becomes: how to display cout without interferences? use a mutex and a lock_guard

Hope that helps,