# ofstream - Can I redirect a "cout" into file?

Tags: c++, fstream, cout, io-redirection, ofstream

I just wanted to know if there was some way yo be able to do this :

```
ofstream exemple (name);
exemple << Display();
```

Display() being a void method, that only do something like that :

```
cout << "Something" << endl;
```

I would do that because I have already written all the methods Display() for each class and I would like to put what they send to cout into my file, instead or recreate some methods "string Display()".

Is it possible?

Thank's! Marco

Comment: you can return the ostream. Or do stream operator overloading(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm), since you said you are using classes.

Comment: I tried it, but a get the error that I cannot return a private member (cout).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You can change `cout`'s buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files), but `cout` is a global variable so that will affect the whole program.

Why don't you make `Display()` receive the output stream as parameter?

```
void Display(std::ostream &cout) {
    cout << "Something" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Very simple and useful!
Thank you!:D

Answer (score 4):

**No, not like that.** You cannot use the result of a `void` function, ever, because it does not have one.

It *is* possible to hack around with the underlying buffer of `std::cout`, swapping it for `example`'s, but *I would not recommend this*... and the code in your question would still be invalid.

You could do this:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>

void Display(std::ostream& os)
{
    os << "Something" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   const std::string name = "someFile.txt";
   std::ofstream example(name);
   Display(example);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Display` a helper function of a manipulator `display_msg`, a class which encapsulates the output. `Display` cannot return `void`, because if you are looking for the syntax `os << Display()` to work, `Display` will have to return something other than `void`.

Here is the definition of `display_msg`:

> ```
> class display_msg { };
> ```

The class is left empty because it performs nothing of importance. We will overload the insertion operator for this class so that we can access the output stream and insert our custom data into:

> ```
> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const display_msg&)
> {
>     return os << "My message";
> }
> ```

This is a very simple setup. But as you said, you would like for the output to be redirected to standard output ( `std::cout` ). For that you will have to copy the buffer of `std::cout` to the file stream. You can do that using RAII (in order to manage lifetime dependencies between the objects):

> ```
> struct copy_buf
> {
> public:
>     copy_buf(std::ios& lhs, std::ios& rhs)
>         : str(lhs), buf(lhs.rdbuf())
>     {
>         lhs.rdbuf(rhs.rdbuf());
>     }
>
>     ~copy_buf() { str.rdbuf(buf); }
> private:
>     std::ios& str;
>     std::streambuf* buf;
> };
> ```

The inserter can use this like so:

> ```
> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const display_msg&)
> {
>     copy_buf copy(os, std::cout);
>     return os << "My message";
> }
> ```

`Display` is a simple helper function that returns the class:

> ```
> display_msg Display()
> {
>      return display_msg();
> }
>
> std::ifstream f("in.txt");
> f << Display(); // redirects to standard output
> ```