# Whitespaces are not being read

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int vovles_count[5] = { 0,0,0,0,0 };
    char vovwls[5] = { 'a','e','i','o','u' };
    char vov;
    int nonVov = 0 , punt = 0 , douseq = 0;

    //std::cin >> std::noskipws; //tells not to skip white spaces

    while (cin >> vov)
    {
        switch (vov)
        {
            case 'a':
                ++vovles_count[0];
                break;
            case 'e':
                ++vovles_count[1];
                break;
            case 'i':
                ++vovles_count[2];
                break;
            case 'o':
                ++vovles_count[3];
                break;
            case 'u':
                ++vovles_count[4];
                break;
            case ' ':
                ++punt;
                break;
            case '\n':
                ++punt;
                break;
            case 'f':
                cin >> vov;
                if (vov == 'l' || vov == 'f')
                {
                    ++douseq;
                    ++nonVov; //previous f
                    ++nonVov; //current f

                } 
                else if (vov == 'i')
                {
                    ++vovles_count[2];
                    ++douseq;
                    ++nonVov;   //previous f
                }
                else if (vov == ' ' || vov == '\n')
                    ++punt;

                break;
            default:
                ++nonVov;
                break;

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << vovwls[i] << " occured for " << vovles_count[i] << "times" << '\n';
    }
    cout << '\n' << nonVov << " are the occurence of non vovels " << '\n' ;
    cout << '\n' << punt << " are the occurence of whitespaces " << '\n';
    cout << '\n' << douseq << " are the occurence of double sequence " << '\n';


    system("pause");
    return 0;
  }
```

I dont think i see any problem in the code but i don't know why white spaces are not being read?

Comment: The `operator>>()` for `char` skips whitespaces by default.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you mean cin does not read whitespaces? How do i modify the code?and btw that's a wonderful meaning for the name!

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, a_string)`  (with `a_string` a `std::string` from the header `<string>`) will read one line of input from `std::cin`.  That string will contain the entered spaces.

Comment: @psraganvesh You can for instance use `cin.read()` to read a certain number of characters including whitespace and newline characters.

Comment: @Peter i saw use std::cin >> std::noskipws;

Comment: That's another way, but also affects extraction of things other than characters in ways that can be counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Peter what if i use noskipws before the while loop and after it use skipws will it later ignore?

Comment: skipws is an enduring setting.    That's part of the problem - particularly if other code expects a stream behaving as it does by default.

Answer (score 0):

using cin will skip white space by default. you can try other ways:

[cin.get();](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/)

exactly this code overload of function would help you:

```
istream& get (char* s, streamsize n, char delim);
```

put '\n' in delim to end input line on pushing enter

Comment: `getch()` and `getche()` are not standard C++.   They are vendor-specific extensions.

Comment: when i use cin.get() im getting the errors saying cout is ambiguous i don't know what that means?

Comment: so you can use [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25538593/6116686) @psraganvesh