# How to write in stdout after using freopen

Tags: c++, c, freopen

After `freopen`-ing `stdout`, How can I print on terminal?

```
freopen("out", "w", stdout); // reopen stdout
/* something */
printf("Now I want to print this on terminal");
```

Comment: Code is easier to understand than English - you should post it.

Comment: On what OS? I believe Windows doesn't necessarily allow this to work...

Comment: @MatsPetersson on the ubuntu

Comment: Then post a small example of what you are doing, and explain what you expect vs. what actually happen.

Comment: @darkdream Do you want to print something in file then something in console?

Comment: @AramGevorgyan   yes...

Comment: I completely edit your question. Please make sure my edit is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

[Once I've used freopen, how can I get the original stdout (or stdin) back?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/undofreopen.html)

There's no portable solution. But the link also explains a possible solution using your own stream and a [non-portable](http://c-faq.com/stdio/rd.kirby.c) solution that'll work on most posix systems.

> There isn't a good way. If you need to switch back, the best solution
>   is not to have used freopen in the first place. Try using your own
>   explicit output (or input) stream variable, which you can reassign at
>   will, while leaving the original stdout (or stdin) undisturbed. For
>   example, declare a global
>
> ```
> FILE *ofp;
> ```
>
> and replace all calls to printf( ... ) with fprintf(ofp, ... ).
>   (Obviously, you'll have to check for calls to putchar and puts, too.)
>   Then you can set ofp to stdout or to anything else.
>
> You might wonder if you could skip freopen entirely, and do something
>   like
>
> ```
> FILE *savestdout = stdout;
> stdout = fopen(file, "w");    /* WRONG */
> ```
>
> leaving yourself able to restore stdout later by doing
>
> ```
> stdout = savestdout;      /* WRONG */
> ```
>
> but code like this is not likely to work, because stdout (and stdin
>   and stderr) are typically constants which cannot be reassigned (which
>   is why freopen exists in the first place).
>
> It may be possible, in a nonportable way, to save away information
>   about a stream before calling freopen to open some file in its place,
>   such that the original stream can later be restored. The most
>   straightforward and reliable way is to manipulate the underlying file
>   descriptors using a system-specific call such as dup or dup2, if
>   available. Another is to copy or inspect the contents of the FILE
>   structure, but this is exceedingly nonportable and unreliable.
>
> Under some systems, you might be able to reopen a special device file
>   (such as /dev/fd/1 under modern versions of Unix) which is still
>   attached to (for example) the original standard output. You can, under
>   some systems, explicitly re-open the controlling terminal, but this
>   isn't necessarily what you want, since the original input or output
>   (i.e. what stdin or stdout had been before you called freopen) could
>   have been redirected from the command line.

Answer (score -4):

You can do it by:

```
#include <fstream> 

ofstream out("out.txt");

out<<"something";

then

cout<<"something";
```

Comment: This not answering the question

Comment: @SHR: Let the man who ask this question to say it is answering or not, may be it's usefull for him

Comment: If you're going to write an answer like this, at least use stdio to be consistent with the question. Otherwise we may have a case of "Q: How do I do this in Java?" "A: Use C# instead."