# Append std output of a function to a file

Tags: c++

Say I have a function. It has prints that output to std.out. Is there a way to capture the print outs of the function alone? Then append the captured output to a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to redirect the program output like `a.out >> output.txt` (this will redirect all output), you can redirect `std::cout` to a file (assuming also you don't want to modify the code in `f()` to use a `fstream`)

Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

void f()
{
    std::cout << "Say something\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Writing to file..." << std::endl;

    std::ofstream ofile("output.txt", std::fstream::app); // output file
    std::streambuf *oldbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); // save the buffer
    std::cout.rdbuf(ofile.rdbuf()); //redirect to output.txt

    f(); // call f

    // now redirect back
    std::cout.rdbuf(oldbuf);

    std::cout << "Done writing to file" << std::endl;
}
```

Note: the above works if you print with `std::cout` and not using `prinf`. You can even write a RAII-like class that automatically redirects `cout` and its destructor redirects back, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

class RAIIcout_redirect
{
    std::streambuf* _oldbuf;
public:
    RAIIcout_redirect(std::ofstream& os): _oldbuf(std::cout.rdbuf())
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(os.rdbuf());
    }
    ~RAIIcout_redirect()
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(_oldbuf);
    }
};

void f()
{
    std::cout << "Say something\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Writing to file..." << std::endl;
    std::ofstream ofile("output.txt", std::fstream::app); // output file

    // local scope, at exit cout is redirected back automatically
    {
        RAIIcout_redirect tmp(ofile);
        f(); // call f
    } // now redirect back because of ~RAIIcout_redirect()

    std::cout << "Done writing to file" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the function src, you can modify the signature to pass in the ostream to which you want that function to write.  Add a default to minimize impact to the other invocations.

header:

```
void foo(int x, int y, std::ostream& an_ostream = std::cout);
```

implementation:

```
void foo(int x, int y, std::ostream& an_ostream)
{
    an_ostream << ...
```

usage out to std::out:

```
foo(1,2);
```

usage to file (simulated with stringstream):

```
std::stringstream ss;
foo(3,4,ss);
```

output to cerr:

```
foo(5,6,std::cerr);
```

suppress output:

```
std::ofstream nullDev; // do not open
// set error, ignore errors
nullDev.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit); 
// do not close

foo(7,8,nullDev);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild suggestion.

1. Prepend every line of output from the function by a unique token.
2. Then, use:

```bash
 a.out | grep <token> | sed -e '1,$s/<token>//' >> output.txt
```