# Make a program work with input and a file

Tags: c++, file, input, getline, cin

I am making a shell interpreter which works only with keyboard input, but I have to make it work with a text files.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
  string comando;
  mi_argv[0] = NULL;
  int pid_aux;    
  el_prompt = "$> ";

  if(argv[1] != NULL)
  {
    ifstream input(argv[1]);
    if (!input)
    {
        cerr << "No se reconoce el archivo " << argv[1] << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  while(!cin.eof())
  {
     cout << el_prompt;
     getline(cin, comando);
  ...
  }
}
```

The point is to make this work with a file like argument `./shell file.txt`. I tried to redirect the file to `cin`, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect cin and cout to files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code reading from the *input stream* in a separate function, and pass a reference to the *input stream* to the function. Then you can pass any input stream to the function, a file you have opened or `std::cin`.

Like e.g.

```
void main_loop(std::istream& input)
{
    // Use `input` here like any other input stream
}
```

Now you can call the function either with standard input

```
main_loop(std::cin);
```

or your file

```
main_loop(input);
```

---

Also, be careful with that loop condition, doing `while (!stream.eof())` will in most cases not work as expected. The reason being that the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond the end of the stream, and will lead to the loop being run one extra time.

Instead do e.g. `while (std::getline(...))`.

Comment: Work perfect with keyboard input, but when i use a file, print all the commands and then print the prompts, maybe a thread problem. I remove the prompt when there is a file, but if you have a better solution i'll appreciate it. Thanks so much!.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


void usage() {
    std::cout << "Usage: shell <filename>\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string comando;
    std::string el_prompt = "$> ";

    if (argc != 2) {
        usage();
        exit(1);
    }

    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
    while (std::getline(input, comando)) {
        std::cout << el_prompt << comando;
    }
}
```

You would need code of course to parse the command and execute it.