# c++ unit testing check output is correct

Tags: c++, unit-testing, output, assert, cout

If I want to write my own test.cpp that checks if another .cpp file is outputting the way I want it to output, is there anyway to do it without explicitly printing it?

In other words, is there anything such as

```
assert(output_of_file_being_tested, "this is the correct output");
```

where output_of_file_being_tested is something that's supposed to be "cout"ed.

Comment: You can do something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files

Comment: Code is more testable if you avoid writing to things like `std::cout` directly and write to `std::ostream&` references. Then the testing framework can pass in `std::ostringstream` objects while the application passes in `std::cout`.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is not to hard-code the output stream. Pass a reference to `std::ostream` to your code somehow, and use `std::stringstream` to collect the output in test environment.

For example, this is the content of your "another .cpp" file:

```
void toBeTested(std::ostream& output) {
        output << "this is the correct output";
}
```

So in your production/release code you may pass `std::cout` to the function:

```
void productionCode() {
        toBeTested(std::cout);
}
```

while in the test environment you may collect the output to a sting stream and check it for correctness:

```
// test.cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

void test() {
        std::stringstream ss;
        toBeTested(ss);
        assert(ss.str() == "this is the correct output");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `Sergey`'s great answer above, you may choose to have `std::cout` as a *default parameter*.
So, if you have a code:

```cpp
// Only need console output
using std::cout;
...
void toBeTested()
{
    cout << "This is the correct output.";
}
```

And it is used (or may be frequently used in the future) in many places:

```cpp
int main()
{
    ...
    toBeTested();
    ...
    toBeTested();
    ...
    // And so on...
    return 0;
}
```

In order to avoid breaking a lot of code and maintaining a simple interface,
you can convert the above function to:

```cpp
using std::cout;
...
void toBeTested(std::ostream& cout = std::cout)
{
    cout << "This is the correct output.";
}
```

And your `main` does not need to be touched.
Note that `cout` of the function now overshadows `cout` of the global scope. Therefore, this `cout` can be any output stream, and does not interfere with the global `cout`.

And now  you can test this as above!

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

...

void testMyFunctionDisplay()
{
    // Arrange
    std::ostringstream output_buffer;

    // Act
    toBeTested(output_buffer);

    // Assert
    assert(output_buffer.str() == "This is the correct output.");
}
```

However. it is not necessary to make every function in this way.

---

It is useful if we want to redirect that function's output to other output streams:

- **Stringstreams**: If you want to use the output somewhere, perhaps for testing the module, or for other purposes in the program.
- **Files**: If you want to maintain the output even after the program termination.