# How do I output the cout output from a method into an ofstream file in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a main function that prints a sudoku game to the console as I play. I call a print board method which outputs the board along with a 2D array with the numbers. I've been modifying the game to output to the file after every cout:

```
cout << "puzzle created" << endl;
output << "puzzle created" << endl;
```

Then the problem is that there is an error when I try the same with a method:

```
sudoku.printBoard(); //method to print board to console
```

I can't simply say:

```
output << sudoku.printBoard();
```

and I can't say:

```
output << "number";
```

in the method in the board.cpp file either.

Does anyone know any way around this?

Comment: `<<` is not I/O redirection (as `>>` in shell) or whatever you think it is. It's a binary operator. Stop guessing.

Comment: Use a reference to `ofstream` as a parameter to `printBoard` method

Comment: Assuming you can't modify the `printBoard` function for some reason, you can try redirecting `cout`'s output to a file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem with `print()` member functions, and the reason you shouldn't write them. At least, not like this. You've locked yourself into printing to *stdout*, and now that you want to print somewhere else instead, you're stuck.

Instead, have a function that prints *where you tell it to*. This may be *stdout* or a file or whatever.

The function will be declared like this:

```
void printBoard(std::ostream& os);
```

and inside its definition, you will use `os` rather than `std::cout`.

Then your code will look like this:

```
sudoku.printBoard(std::cout);
sudoku.printBoard(output);
```

It works because both `std::cout` and `output` are of types that derive from `std::ostream`.

---

If you need the `cout` variant a lot, and you don't want to provide the argument every time because it's getting messy, simply provide an overload:

```
void printBoard()
{
    printBoard(std::cout);
}
```

Now you can still write:

```
sudoku.printBoard();
```

Whether this is more or less confusing for developers on your project is for you to decide.

---

If you don't have other things to print, so that this is the only function of its kind within the type of `sudoku`, a more idiomatic approach would be to create an `operator<<` for that type:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SudokuBoard& board)
{
    board.printBoard(os);
    return os;
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
std::cout << sudoku;
output << sudoku;
```

Comment: I was using an ofstream .txt file.  

    ofstream output;
    output.open("output.txt", ios::out); 

will there be any issue with this?

Comment: @wanklenoodle: No; this is how streams are designed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `ofstream` as a reference to your funtion or simply return string from your function and print it in `main()` or callee function.

### In 2nd case you go like this

```
string f()
{
   ostringstream os;
   os<<"whatever I want to print in output";
   ....
   ...
   return os.str();
}
int main() or //womain() from wherever you call
{
   output<<f()<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that takes two ostreams in the constructor. One of these can be std::cout. Store these in the class as references.

Create output stream operators (<<) and use those to write to the two streams.

To use this in other classes pass it as a reference in their constructor (look up dependency injection).