# function freopen is not reading inputs

Tags: c++, input, stdin, cin, freopen

I'm trying to test `freopen("inputs.txt","r",stdin);` but it is not working.Here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    freopen("inputs.txt","r",stdin);

    int n;
    cin >> n;

    cout << n << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There is only one integer number in my input file and it is in the same directory.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `cin` is not the same as `stdin`, it won't be affected by the `freopen()` call.

Comment: Here's a way how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files/10151286

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I had a problem with the file path.File path should be in full form like

`freopen("Users/mahfuz/inputs.txt","r",stdin);`

this worked for me.