# redirect cout to a file

Tags: c++, cout

I want to redirect cout to a file when needed. Here is the main part of my test program, but I can't figure out some input was not directed to the file.

```
     ucla();
     ucla() { 
        std::cout << "inside ucla" << std::endl;
      }

     int main() {
           const char* outName = argv[2];                                                                                          
           std::string outFile(outName);                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
           std::streambuf *coutbuf, *termbuf;                                                                                      
           termbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
           if (!outFile.empty()) {                                                                                                         
                 std::ofstream outstr;                                                                                                   
                 outstr.open(argv[2]);                                                                                                   
                 coutbuf = outstr.rdbuf();                                                                                               
                 std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);                                                                                               
                 std::cout << "here" << std::endl;                                                                               
           } else {std::cout.rdbuf(termbuf);}                                                                                                                                                                                                              
           std::cout << "this file " << std::endl;  

          ucla();
          }
```

When the program is run, only here was written to the file, I expect 
this file 
inside ucla
I searched earlier threads, and I can't figure out what is missing. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files

Comment: You can also use the linux I/O redirection. ex: ./program > file.txt

Comment: I looked into the previous post to learn about streambuf, but it does not seem to work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior.

`coutbuf` is destructed when `outstr` is destructed. Since you didn't reset the `rdbuf` of `cout` when the `if`-block ended, `cout` points to a dangling `rdbuf` outside the `if`-block.

---

Suggestion for cleanup. Always provide a return type for functions. Instead of

```
ucla();
```

use

```
void ucla();
```

---

#### Update, in response to OP's comment

To resolve the problem, it will be good to move all the "application code" to another function and call that function from `main`. Leave the `rdbuf` handling code in `main`.

```
void ucla()
{
   std::cout << "inside ucla" << std::endl;
}

void application_main()
{
   std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "this file " << std::endl;
   ucla();
}

int main()
{
   const char* outName = argv[2];
   std::string outFile(outName);

   // Save the rdbuf of cout.
   std::streambuf* coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();

   termbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
   if (!outFile.empty())
   {
      std::ofstream outstr;
      outstr.open(argv[2]);
      std::cout.rdbuf(outstr.rdbuf());

      // Needs to be here so that every use of cout will redirect the output
      // to the file.
      application_main();
   }
   else
   {
      // In this branch, use of cout will produce output in the console.
      application_main();
   }

   // Restore the rdbuf of cout.
   std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
}
```

Comment: Any suggestion one what I can do? I need to be able to send the output to the output file if it were not empty, I be able to send the cout to the file, otherwise, it will be just cout.

Comment: Better: have `application_main()` take a `std::ostream&` argument and then call it with `std::cout` or an opened `std::ofstream` depending.

Comment: @Shawn, Your suggestion will definitely be a better option if the application is as simple as the posted cod. iI there are other functions in the same file or functions in other files, you can't freely use `cout` and get the output redirected to a file. You'll have to pass the `ostream` object to every downstream function and use it instead of using `cout`. That would be tedious, I think.