# Is there a way to output everything that would show in the console window into a .txt?

Tags: c++

for an assignment I wrote a program and we hit start without debugging to use the program and the console would ask questions and such. As part of this assignment, we have to write everything that appears in the console window (in visual studio, when we hit start without debugging or ctrl+f5) to a .txt file. Is there a way to have every cout statement write to this file or do I have to type it out on every line that i want to be written to the .txt?

using the ofstream with #include fstream for this by the way

Comment: 1) "Everything that appears in the console window" includes your input; do you need to write it as well? It'll complicate the matters a lot. 2) Do you have to do this in your program? For this I always use [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)).

Comment: 1) yes, we also have to include the input that the "user" of the program would type.

2. yes, we have to write everything that would appear in the console window to a .txt.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I never did this, so I may be unaware of some issues). If you have to do this in the code, you can define your own class for which you define `operator <<`, so that it prints to both console and file. This way there will be no duplication.

Comment: hmm.. sorry i am really new to coding i just started a few weeks ago. if you are able to, would you be willing to give me an example of what i would write and where i should put it? thanks for your help though!

Comment: I think this example may help to understand how `ostream` and `operator <<` work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019. Think about it this way: you want to print something to both console and file, so you should define a function which does it (something like `template<typename T> void print(T output) { cout << output; fout << output; }`). It should already work (so maybe it's enough for you), but to match the standard stream syntax, you can define your own class and your own `operator <<`.

Comment: thank you for your help dyukha! i will look into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect cin and cout to files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)