# Copy std::cout inside a std::ofstream (c++)

Tags: c++, file, logging, fstream, cout

i am currently trying to make a very basic "logging system" and I would like to copy std::cout contents inside a std::ofstream to make a "log" file to print what i sent to the cout.

```
std::cout << "[LOG] My log message\n";
std::cout << "[LOG] My log message2\n";
std::ofstream s("Log.txt");
//std::cout >> s; ????????????
```

This is how i tried to do it but without success.
I expect Log.txt to have:

```
[LOG] My log message
[LOG] My log message2
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files) might help you.

Comment: Once you write to an output stream, that information is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a cake and eat it in the same time. Each stream object can only be tied to a single buffer, and `std::cout` does not go backwards (you can write to it, but you can't read from it).

Because of that, while you can redirect `cout` to go to any other stream, this will only be effective for output happened **after** redirection. There is absolutely no way for you to force the data which was printed to `cout` **before** to appear in any other stream **now**, unless you have a way to recreate the data or extract it from some other storage (not cout).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create your own T (Tee) stream, by deriving your own class from a `std::ostream`.

That is rather simple and basically you just need to override the streams `sync` and `overflow` function, and send the data to both desired outputs.

You can find a complete example of a Tee stream [here](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC/blob/master/mcdc/Include/cloption.hpp) and [here](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC/blob/master/mcdc/Source/cloption.cpp).

In this example code, I select where the output goes to with command line options. And, the beauty of it, you can use all existing IO-stream facilities. And, it is fully transparent.