# "Exception thrown: read access violation. aproc was nullptr."

Tags: c++

I wrote a program and I have an input file (input10.txt). I am having trouble running the code. I am getting "Exception thrown: read access violation. aproc was nullptr."
Can someone please run the program please? I might be making an error when trying to input.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Input file:

```
NCORES 2
NEW   10 
CORE   100   
INPUT 5000  
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   1     
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   0     
CORE   30    
SSD   1     
CORE   20    
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   0     
CORE  40    
SSD   1     
CORE   20    
NEW  20  
CORE   40   
SSD   1
CORE 100
SSD 1
CORE 200
SSD 1
CORE 50
INPUT 5000  
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   1     
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   1     
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE 40
NEW 50
CORE   40   
SSD   1
CORE 100
SSD 1
CORE 200
SSD 1
CORE 50
INPUT 5000  
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   1     
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   1     
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE 40
NEW  60  
CORE   40   
SSD   1
CORE 100
SSD 1
CORE 200
SSD 1
CORE 50
INPUT 5000  
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   1     
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   1     
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE 40
NEW 80
CORE   40   
SSD   1
CORE 100
SSD 1
CORE 200
SSD 1
CORE 50
INPUT 1000  
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   1     
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE   80    
SSD   1     
CORE 100
SSD  1
CORE 40
```

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct process;

struct instruction
{
    string instruct;
    int value;
    instruction* next = NULL;
    instruction* prev = NULL;
    process* proc = NULL;
    instruction* nexQ = NULL;
};

struct process
{
    int procNum;
    process* next = NULL;
    process* prev = NULL;
    instruction* link = NULL;
    string state = "";
};

void readInstruction(instruction* ainstruc);
void readProcess(process* aproc);
void update(int time);

void endProcess(process* toTerminate);
void printStatus();
void printSummary();

instruction* nextReady = new instruction;
instruction* readyQ = nextReady;
instruction* nextInput = new instruction;
instruction* inputQ = nextInput;
instruction* nextSSD = new instruction;
instruction* ssdQ = nextSSD;

instruction* headInstruct = new instruction;
instruction* currentInstruct = headInstruct;
process* headProcess = new process;
process* currentProcess = headProcess;

ifstream file;
ofstream output;

int cores = 0;
instruction** coreInstructs = NULL;
int* coreTimes = NULL;
instruction* ioDevice = NULL;
int ioTime = -1;
instruction* SSD = NULL;
int ssdTime = -1;
instruction** tempArr = NULL;
int processes = 0;
int timeNow = 0;

int ssdAccesses = 0;
int ssdSum = 0;
int coreSum = 0;


int main()
{
    string fileName;
    cin >> fileName;

    file.open(fileName);
    if (file.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    string word;
    cin >> word;
    cin >> cores;
    //cores = stoi(word);
    coreInstructs = new instruction * [cores];
    coreTimes = new int[cores];
    for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++)
    {
        coreInstructs[i] = NULL;
        coreTimes[i] = -1;
    }
    tempArr = new instruction * [cores + 2];

    while (cin >> word)
    {
        instruction* newInstruct = new instruction;
        newInstruct->instruct = word;
        if (word == "NEW")
        {
            process* newProcess = new process;
            newProcess->procNum = processes;
            processes++;
            newProcess->link = newInstruct;
            newProcess->prev = currentProcess;
            currentProcess->next = newProcess;
            currentProcess = currentProcess->next;
        }
        cin >> newInstruct->value;
        newInstruct->proc = currentProcess;
        newInstruct->prev = currentInstruct;
        currentInstruct->next = newInstruct;
        currentInstruct = currentInstruct->next;
    }
    file.close();

    readProcess(headProcess->next);
    printSummary();

    return 0;
}

void readInstruction(instruction* ainstruc)
{
    switch ((ainstruc->instruct)[0])
    {
    case 'C':
    {
        coreSum += ainstruc->value;
        bool full = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++)
            if (coreInstructs[i] == NULL)
            {
                full = false;
                ainstruc->proc->state = "RUNNING";
                coreInstructs[i] = ainstruc;
                coreTimes[i] = ainstruc->value + timeNow;
                break;
            }
        if (full)
        {
            ainstruc->proc->state = "READY";
            readyQ->nexQ = ainstruc;
            readyQ = readyQ->nexQ;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 'I':
    {
        ainstruc->proc->state = "BLOCKED";
        if (ioDevice == NULL)
        {
            ioDevice = ainstruc;
            ioTime = ainstruc->value + timeNow;
        }
        else
        {
            inputQ->nexQ = ainstruc;
            inputQ = inputQ->nexQ;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 'S':
    {
        ssdAccesses++;
        ssdSum += ainstruc->value;
        if (SSD == NULL)
        {
            ainstruc->proc->state = "RUNNING";
            SSD = ainstruc;
            ssdTime = ainstruc->value + timeNow;
        }
        else
        {
            ainstruc->proc->state = "READY";
            ssdQ->nexQ = ainstruc;
            ssdQ = ssdQ->nexQ;
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}

void readProcess(process* aproc)
{
    update(aproc->link->value);
    cout << "Process " << (aproc->procNum) << " starts at time " << timeNow << " ms" << endl;
    printStatus();
    readInstruction(aproc->link->next);

    if (aproc->next != NULL)
        readProcess(aproc->next);
    else
        update(INT_MAX);
}

void update(int time)
{
    int maxTime = -1;
    instruction* maxInstruc = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++)
        if (coreTimes[i] < time)
            if (coreTimes[i] > maxTime)
            {
                maxTime = coreTimes[i];
                maxInstruc = coreInstructs[i];
            }
    if (ioTime < time)
        if (ioTime > maxTime)
        {
            maxTime = ioTime;
            maxInstruc = ioDevice;
        }
    if (ssdTime < time)
        if (ssdTime > maxTime)
        {
            maxTime = ssdTime;
            maxInstruc = SSD;
        }
    if (maxTime != -1)
    {
        switch (maxInstruc->instruct[0])
        {
        case 'C':
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++)
            {
                if (coreInstructs[i] == maxInstruc)
                {
                    update(coreTimes[i]);
                    instruction* temp = coreInstructs[i];
                    coreInstructs[i] = NULL;
                    coreTimes[i] = -1;
                    if (nextReady->nexQ != NULL)
                    {
                        coreInstructs[i] = nextReady->nexQ;
                        coreTimes[i] = coreInstructs[i]->value + timeNow;
                        coreInstructs[i]->proc->state = "RUNNING";
                        nextReady = nextReady->nexQ;
                    }
                    if (temp->next != NULL)
                    {
                        if (temp->next->instruct == "NEW")
                            endProcess(temp->proc);
                        else
                            readInstruction(temp->next);
                    }
                    else
                        endProcess(temp->proc);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'I':
        {
            update(ioTime);
            instruction* temp = ioDevice;
            ioDevice = NULL;
            ioTime = -1;
            if (nextInput->nexQ != NULL)
            {
                ioDevice = nextInput->nexQ;
                ioTime = ioDevice->value + timeNow;
                ioDevice->proc->state = "BLOCKED";
                nextInput = nextInput->nexQ;
            }
            if (temp->next != NULL)
            {
                if (temp->next->instruct == "NEW")
                    endProcess(temp->proc);
                else
                    readInstruction(temp->next);
            }
            else
                endProcess(temp->proc);
            break;
        }
        case 'S':
        {
            update(ssdTime);
            instruction* temp = SSD;
            SSD = NULL;
            ssdTime = -1;
            if (nextSSD->nexQ != NULL)
            {
                SSD = nextSSD->nexQ;
                ssdTime = SSD->value + timeNow;
                SSD->proc->state = "RUNNING";
                nextSSD = nextSSD->nexQ;
            }
            if (temp->next != NULL)
            {
                if ((temp->next->instruct) == "NEW")
                    endProcess(temp->proc);
                else
                    readInstruction(temp->next);
            }
            else
                endProcess(temp->proc);
            break;
        }
        }
        update(time);
    }
    if (time != INT_MAX)
        timeNow = time;
}

void endProcess(process* toTerminate)
{
    toTerminate->state = "TERMINATED";
    cout << "Process " << toTerminate->procNum << " terminates at time " << timeNow << " ms" << endl;
    printStatus();
    toTerminate->state = "";
}

void printStatus()
{
    process* temp = headProcess;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        if (temp->state != "")
            cout << "Process " << temp->procNum << " is " << temp->state << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void printSummary()
{
    cout << "SUMMARY:" << endl;
    cout << "Number of processes that completed: " << processes << endl;
    cout << "Total number of SSD accesses: " << ssdAccesses << endl;
    if (ssdAccesses == 0)
        cout << "Average SSD access time: " << 0 << " ms" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Average SSD access time: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << (double(ssdSum) / ssdAccesses) << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "Total elapsed time: " << timeNow << " ms" << endl;
    if (timeNow == 0)
    {
        cout << "Core utilization: " << 0 << " percent" << endl;
        cout << "SSD utilization: " << 0 << " percent" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Core utilization: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << ((double(coreSum) / timeNow) * 100) << " percent" << endl;
        cout << "SSD utilization: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << ((double(ssdSum) / timeNow) * 100) << " percent" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect cin and cout to files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)

Comment: You don't do anything with the file after you open it. Seems to work fine [when I read the input by cin](https://godbolt.org/z/4b7c74)

Comment: Everywhere you have input like `cin >> word;` use `file >> word;` instead.

Comment: I changed cin >> word; to file >> word;  when prompted I entered                                      ` input10.txt  2 NEW` `Process 0 starts at time 0 ms

Process 1 starts at time 0 ms

Process 2 starts at time 0 ms

Process 3 starts at time 0 ms

Process 4 starts at time 0 ms

SUMMARY:
Number of processes that completed: 5
Total number of SSD accesses: 0
Average SSD access time: 0 ms
Total elapsed time: 0 ms
Core utilization: 0 percent
SSD utilization: 0 percent`

Comment: What did you guys entered as input when prompted?

Comment: Assuming you fixed *all* input to read from the file and not just the one example I mentioned your next step would be to step through the code in a debugger so you can watch what is happening and see if that matches up with what you think should happen. You might start with a much smaller input set to simplify the problem.