# How to redirect std::cout to file conditionally

Tags: c++

In my code I have a a function that takes as argument a boolean variable. If this variable is true then the output shall be redirected to a file. If not, then to `std::cout`

The code looks like this and Its been inspired by a relevant question [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)

```
void MyClass::PPrint(bool ToFile)
{
    
        std::streambuf *coutBufferBak = std::cout.rdbuf();
        std::ofstream   out("out.txt");
        
        if (ToFile) { std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); }

        std::cout << "Will I be written to a file or to cout ?\n";

        if (ToFile) {std::cout.rdbuf(coutBufferBak);} // reset cout
  
}
```

But in the case that the `ToFile` flag is `false` the file will be generated nonetheless and it will be empty. Is there a way to do it so that the file won't be generated ? If for example I try to include on the first IF statement the `std::ofstream out("out.txt");` then I will get a `SegFault` due to the the variable scope being limited to that if.

Comment: Why can't you simply defer the opening/creation of `out.txt` until the body of the `if (ToFile)` conditional?

Comment: you need not redirect `std::cout` when you can just choose between `std::cout` and a file stream

Comment: It looks like you should wrap the `rdbuf` logic into a class. This gives you RAII behavior; the dtor will automatically reset `cout`. You can then use a `std::optional<>` wrapper to handle the conditional part.

Comment: FWIW, I would change the function to `void MyClass::PPrint(ostream& out)`, then the function body just becomes `out << sutff_to_output`.  This allows users of the function to print to any stream, and also the ability to pick a different file location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't redirect `std::cout`. Write your print in terms of a `std::ostream &` parameter, and choose an appropriate `std::ostream` to pass.

```
void MyClass::PPrintImpl(std::ostream & out)
{
    out << "Will I be written to a file or to cout ?\n";
}

// a.k.a 

std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & out, const MyClass &)
{
    return out << "Will I be written to a file or to cout ?\n";
}

void MyClass::PPrint(bool ToFile) {
    if (ToFile) {
        std::ofstream fout("out.txt");
        PPrintImpl(fout);
    } else {
        PPrintImpl(std::cout);
    }
}
```

We pass `std::ostream`s by reference because we the identity, not just the value of the stream object matters. We know this because they aren't copyable ([the copy constructor is `delete`d](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream))

Comment: Clean programming wise, this seems to me the best practice. Thank you. I've been quite struggling with ```c++``` and this seems very handy. Could you elaborate maybe on why the ```operator ``` is needed in this case if possible?  And why the ```ostreams``` must be passed as refferences to the functions.Thanks again.

Comment: @Broxigar It isn't *needed*. It's just that the conventional name of a "write to output stream" function is `operator <<`

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file conditionally:

```
std::ofstream out;
if(...)
    out.open("out.txt");
```