# How to quickly write same thing to cin every time program is run?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cin

I'm currently using C++ and VSCode for competitive programming in USACO. Recently, they changed their input format from file input to inputting data from terminal/stdin, which is slower because I have to paste the input into the terminal every time. Is there a way to just write data to a file and have it inputted into cin every time I run my program?

Comment: Are you looking for input redirection? Something like `myProgram < myFile.txt`?

Comment: You can make cin read from a file (but you need to undo it before submitting obviously) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files

Answer (score 0):

I personally use custom run configuration `< input > myoutput && diff myoutput output` with [CodeRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) to read input and compare with expected output.

For example in case of C++,
In VSCode's `settings.json`, modify the `code-runner.executorMap` as below and use Ctrl+Alt+N to run

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
        ...
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt < input > myoutput && diff myoutput output",
        ...
}
```

input - input to your program
output - the expected output from your program
myoutput - the actual output of your program.